# How to organise MySQL database to store this XML data

Tags: mysql, xml

So I have this XML file:

```
<menu>

<!-- Drinks -->
<category name="Drinks">
    <item name="Coke">
        <type desc="0,5L" price="1"/>
        <type desc="1,0L" price="2"/>
    </item>
    <item name="Pepsi">
        <type desc="0,5L" price="1"/>
        <type desc="1,0L" price="2"/>
    </item>
    <item name="Mountain Dew">
        <type desc="1,0L" price="2"/>
    </item>
</category>

<!-- Pizza -->
<category name="Pizza" details="Small (6 slices) - Medium (8 slices) - Large (10 slices) - XXL (12 slices)">

    <item name="Spicy Samba" details="Carioca sauce, Italian style sausage, ham, onions, fresh tomatoes and Italian style three-cheese blend">
        <type desc="Large Original" price="15"/>
        <type desc="Large Stuffed" price="17"/>
        <type desc="Large Thin" price="16"/>
    </item>

    <item name="Sausage and Pepperoni">
        <type desc="Large Original" price="15"/>
        <type desc="Large Stuffed" price="17"/>
        <type desc="Large Thin" price="16"/>
    </item>

</category>


<!-- Chicken -->
<category name="Chicken">

    <item name="Piri Piri Chicken Wings (6)"><type price="5.5"/></item>
    <item name="Plain Roasted Chicken Wings (6)"><type price="4.5"/></item>

</category>

</menu>
```

And I'd like to make a MySQL database to store this data.

At first I considered one large table with the following columns: RestaurantID, CategoryName, CategoryDetails, ItemName, ItemDetails, Type, Price

But of course, inserting one small Coke would require a lot of repetition of the previous fields.

I then thought about separating my tables into: Categories, Items, and Types, with each linking back to the previous one with a foreign key (just an auto-incrementing integer ID)

But then, it becomes really difficult to keep track of all those IDs. I do intend in the future to make a simple application to make creating this data a lot easier, but before I do that, I'd like my tables to be solid.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating Categories, Items, Types and Prices. I suspect that you'll have a lot of repetitious types, but with varying prices. So the Types table might have `TypeID, TypeDescription` and the Prices table would have `ItemID, TypeID, Price`, with a composite key `(ItemID, TypeID)`.

As far as the data being easy to read, it won't be - in its raw form. But that's pretty common when you have normalized data with any degree of complexity. That's what we have queries for. Writing a query to make your data readable would be fairly simple:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName
     , c.CategoryDetails
     , i.ItemName
     , i.ItemDetails
     , t.TypeDescription
     , p.Price
  FROM categories c
  JOIN items      i ON c.CategoryID = i.CategoryID
  JOIN prices     p ON i.ItemID = p.ItemID
  JOIN types      t ON p.TypeID = t.TypeID;
```